# Ethminer 0.9.41-genoil-1.1.9, fails to submit Hashrate

Tags: windows, miner

I am new to this mining, I started yesterday with downloading the chains for geth and today it finished and so I got the newest version of ethminer. But when I start it this comes:

JSON-RPC problem. Probably couldn't connect. Retrying in 1...
  m  17:30:29|main  Getting work package...
  X  17:30:30|main  Failed to submit hashrate.
  X  17:30:30|main  Dynamic exception type: class jsonrpc::JsonRpcException
std::exception::what: Exception -32003 : Client connector error: libcurl error: 7 -> Could not connect to http://127.0.0.1:8545

I have searched in several Forums about this, but I don't know what to do? 
Please help thanks! Btw. I am using the latest version of windows 10 and use a gtx 1060 3gb.
Andy

Comment: Hi there. It looks like your mining software isn't able to connect to Geth on port 8545. What command and flags did you use to start Geth?

Comment: I just used geth -rpc in the command prompt and that just added chains and did his thing.

Comment: Try restarting Geth using `--rpc --rpcport 8545`.

Comment: Great - glad it worked! :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment discussion, this error:

> libcurl error: 7 -> Could not connect to http://127.0.0.1:8545

...is the important part.

To ensure Geth exposes this port (`8545`) as an RPC interface, it should be started with the `--rpc --rpcport 8545` options.